# Network setup not working.  Can't connect to the Internet in Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, networking

I want to know how to set-up network in 12.04 using automatic settings (DHCP).  I installed Ubuntu, but I can't seen to see the network connection.  What can I do?

My notebook has no wireless only cable.  The cable will not fit in. How can I plug it in?  Do I need a special Cable? There is no router can I fix this myself, or should I call a technician?

Also can I use USB to connect to the network/Internet?

please can you help

Thank you

jamel

Comment: A bit more information would be useful. What is the notebook model you have?

Comment: You say the cable will not fit in, maybe its phone jack and not a network jack. can you include a picture?

Comment: no have camera but yes phone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doesn't look like you have any network cards in the notebook. You can add a wired or wireless USB network card, depending on how you want to connect to the network.  Now if you notebook have a PCMCIA socket, which it probably does, you can get a PCMCIA network card, and that would be better.

[image]

Comment: yes i have Modem not 10Base T. thank you